# play .swf file in html5 video tag

Tags: html, flash, video

we want to play .swf files in html5 video tag.we know that it only supports certain formats but we don't want to convert our files.Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: No, you must convert.

Answer (score 1):

I think video tag only supports webM, mp4 and ogg files, so you might have to export the swf file to any of these formats. I think you might be able to do it in Flash or some other video converters (not sure).